# TYPO3 userRepository return NULL

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 version 7.6.18.

In controller of my extension I have

```
/**
 * @var \Fhk\Feusersplus\Domain\Repository\UserRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $userRepository;
```

In action I try

```
var_dump($this->userRepository);
```

And problem is that it return non object, NULL! Why ?? I have cleaned all caches, delete rows from cf_extbase_reflection and delete typo3temp.

In my other extensions it working! Do you have any ideas ? Help me please )

Comment: Did you use the "Clear all Caches" button in the install tool? Usually that works find. Manually deleting `typo3temp` or database rows should not be necessary.

Comment: +1 for @Jost , you need to clear the cache for TYPO3 to read your annotations anew, that should clear the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the repository object manually (you need the objectManager from your abstractAction or you have to create the objectManager also):

```
$this->userRepository = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Domain\\Repository\\FrontendUserRepository');
```